# Classic asp "Application debugging is disabled" in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, asp-classic, visual-studio-2015

I try to debug a classic asp website, but Visual Studio 2015 says "application debugging is disabled" in the solution explorer when I connect to iisexpress process.

I tried to follow this guide:
[link](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/debugging-classic-asp-with-visual-studio)

Comment: Having the same problem, it was working fine with 2013.

Comment: The link of the blog changed to: https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/debugging-classic-asp-with-visual-studio it helped me to make it work with iis and visual studio 2015

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference with Visual Studio 2015 is that you need to modify

```
<<solutiondir>>\.vs\config\applicationhost.config
```

as opposed to the applicationhost.config in

```
%USERPROFILE%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config
```

Comment: I have this same problem in VS 2015 and VS 2019, but this did not solve it. Does anyone else have any other suggestions?

Comment: Same with me. It sometimes works, sometiems doesn't. Right now, consistantly doesn't